# pthread_kill: What signal to use so it doesn't interfere with program execution?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm currently implementing a tracing system in our program that relies sending signals to individual threads / lightweight processes using pthread_kill. My problem lies in deciding what signal to use so it doesn't interfere with program execution otherwise. Basically, I have 3 requirements for the signal type:

- It should be sendable to a signal thread / lightweight process
- It should not terminate the program
- It should be catcheable by common tracing tools like gdb or strace.

I used SIGUSR2 at the beginning, but I think there are some platforms that will call terminate if it occurs.

Is there a signal type that is guaranteed to be visible by the abovementioned tracing tools and not terminate the process?

Regards

Comment: "but I think there are some platforms that will call terminate if it occurs." why do you think that?  https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Signals.html states (my highlighting) "the *DEFAULT* action is to terminate" - not "it will always terminate".  As long as you don't call `exit()` and you're using something that supports signals (eg not arduino) then it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Ok, is there a signal that doesn't usually terminate, even on default? And that is caught by gdb by default (or with little effort)?